# How to perform Automation testing for two-three days business process

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, playwright, playwright-typescript

I'm relatively new to Automation testing. I've seen notes on automation testing for Static web pages and dynamic ones, even data driven. But in my project, we've got a web page where we load trades and wait until next day to settle it. My question is there any best practice for testing such process where the e2e takes more than 2 to 4 days to complete ? Even if I can perform steps independent, on day 1 I won't be able to pass anything. As mentioned, I'm very new to Automation and still learning, kindly let me know

I'm currently trying to use Playwright with Typescript to build framework, since our front end is React js. I'm not sure how I can automate test a 2-5 days process

Answer (score 1):

### Use [Mocking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)

I think using Mocking will be a good idea in your scenario if you are dependent on third party services, APIs or external systems which are time consuming.

You may use Mocking directly in playwright tests as well with https://playwright.dev/docs/mock

Mocking will help you to simulate the behavior of these external dependencies, making your tests faster, more deterministic, and less reliant on external resources.

Although the trade-off will be it won't be truly E2E tests but definitely will add value in validation with dramatic improvement in feedback time especially where the time taking processes are external to your actual AUT.